# CouchDB _design document conflict detection

Tags: couchdb

I am aware that CouchDB identifies documents that are in conflict after replication. Does CouchDB handle conflict detection differently for _design documents than it does for regular documents? For example, I modify a _design document in DB1. I then modify the same _design document in DB2. I then replicate DB1 to DB2. I would expect that CouchDB identify a conflict, however after replication, Couch returns no conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Design documents are exactly like normal documents, hence the name "design documents" instead of "couch programs" or such.

If you make identical modifications to identical documents in different databases, you will have **no** conflicts. Running `couchapp push` could create this situation, if you push the same app to two different databases (and they had the same `_rev` to begin with).

Otherwise, you will get a conflict, whether design document or no. Of course, couch will "promote" one revision as the canonical version, but if you check for `_conflicts` in a view, you will see them. (To see design documents in a view, you must also enable the `include_design` option.)

```
{ "_id": "_design/example"
, "views":
  { "conflicts":
    { "options": {"include_design": true}
    , "map": "function(doc) { if(doc._conflicts) emit(doc._id, doc._conflicts); }"
    }
  }
}
```

Find conflicting ddocs using a key range scan:

```
?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"
```

Comment: We have a view for _conflicts for all our non_design documents. However,  _design documents do not work with views. Any suggestions as to how to get a list of all _design documents in conflict after a successful replication would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. Design documents *do* work with views but that is an optional setting, and the default is `false`. Once you activate it, you will see ddoc conflicts. (You could also put this in a totally separate view, up to you.)

Comment: I had to put options next to views, not in a view, it then effected all views. I am using version 1.2.0 and have not seen anything in change logs to suggest that one can put options in individual views.